# Monetary.of(new BigDecimal("100.00"), "EUR") prints "EUR 1E+2"

Tags: java-money, jsr354

So here's the question: why this:

```
Monetary.of(new BigDecimal("100.00"), "EUR")
```

prints "EUR 1E+2", but any other decimal != .00 will print correct:

```
Monetary.of(new BigDecimal("100.01"), "EUR")
```

"EUR 100.01"???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK,

it looks like the `MonetaryAmount` calls toString() which will call the `engineeringString` of the `BigDecimal`. The correct way to print a `MonetaryAmount` is to format it:

```
MonetaryFormats.getAmountFormat(Locale.getDefault()).format(Money.of(source.getValue(), source.getCurrency().getUid()))
```

Comment: I think that this is a bug and should be reported. Internal representation of BigDecimal shouldn't affect MonetaryAmount

Comment: Have you already reported it? Also where did getCurrency().getUid() come from? I'm not aware, the API of CurrencyUnit contains this method right now and I have a pretty good understanding of that API ;-)